# Node blog dislpay all content type blog in theme

Tags: nodes, theming

I have content type page with node called blog(page blog) and I want to display all content type blog in it(content of page blog). how can i do this in theme without using block or views.I'm try to do it by using this code:

```
<?php 
$build = array();
$query = db_select('node', 'n')->extend('PagerDefault');
$nids = $query
    ->fields('n', array('nid', 'sticky', 'created'))
    ->condition('type', 'blog')
    ->condition('status', 1)
    ->orderBy('sticky', 'DESC')
    ->orderBy('created', 'DESC')
    ->limit(3)
    ->addTag('node_access')
    ->execute()
    ->fetchCol();

if (!empty($nids)) {
    $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
    $build += node_view_multiple($nodes,'full');
    $build['pager'] = array(
        '#theme' => 'pager',
        '#weight' => 5,
    );
}
else {
    drupal_set_message(t('No blog entries have been created.'));
}

    print render($build);
  ?>
```

and set it in body field for page blog. And when display blog page it's content nothing (or empty page!). I'm test my code and execute it in php code it work and print all blog that I have.
Any way to do this in Drupal theme?

Answer (score 1):

if I understand correctly you'll need this query:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery;
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'blog')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1);

$result = $query->execute();
```

then do you foreach($result);

Comment: It's same nothing display in page by use your code idea! Thanks